# Inject javascript on frame

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, overriding

I'm developing a firefox add-on, and i want to inject a javascript function that overrides the confirm(). The frame is the one that fires the confirm() function, and i want to be able to always return true to this.

I've trying this:

```
var spt = document.createElement("script");
spt.innerHTML = "window.frames['the_frame'].window.confirm = function(msg, cb){return true;};";
window.content.document.head.appendChild(spt);
```

This code is inside a function in a "onclick" event of my extension (it's a toolbar, on the footer of the browser).

But that way, seems to work on the console of the browser, but when i click on the button, the inject works, but the confirm() function is not being overrided.

Anyone can help? Any other ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For who get here to get an answer, i found how to do this:

```
//Initialize the window content
var doc = window.content.document;

//Create a script element
var spt = doc.createElement("script");
//Add a script overriding the confirm ON the frame
spt.innerHTML = "window.frames['the_frame'].confirm = function(msg){return true;};";

//Inject javascript
window.content.document.head.appendChild(spt);
```

Inject the script created element on the top window.
This worked for me!

Comment: Thx for sharing! But this method won't be approved by AMO editors (the people that review the addons for acceptance on addons.mozilla.org) you need to import the script. So create a `chrome.manifest` file and put the scripts in a foldre and in `chrome.manifest` set `contentaccessible=true` on that path. If you would like to go this way let me know and I'll post this solution.

Comment: This add-on is for the company i work only. I'll not upload this.

Is just a tool to get the job done easily.
Thx